# Validate one column only has numbers using Regular Expression

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, regexp-like

I need to verify one column only has numbers(integer number only) in oracle . If yes then set flag as 1 otherwise 0. I am trying to use below reg_exp( but it sets flag to 1 even for hyphen ):

```
CASE WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(Column_name,'\d\) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Examples:
12345 should  ( this is working and above code is setting flag to 1)
-1234 should set flag to 0 ( above code is setting it to 1)
abcd should set flag to 0 ( above code is working correct in this case)
123.23 should set flag to 0

Answer (score 3):

If you want check if contain only digit or not  try

```
CASE WHEN  REGEXP_LIKE(Column_name, '^[[:digit:]]+$') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use `TRANSLATE` function

```
SELECT case when TRANSLATE(Column_name, 'X0123456789', 'X') is null
            then 1
            else 0
       end
FROM t;
```